# Function that calls a function with the terminal temporarily set to raw mode

Tags: beginner, console, callback, unix, ocaml

I'm working through [Build Your Own Text Editor](http://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/index.html), a walkthrough of the code to an extremely small text editor for a posix terminal in C, but I'm attempting to follow along in-the-spirit with OCaml.

I've put together a function that wraps an parameter function with termcap stuff to get the terminal into raw mode. This code works, but it feels ugly to me, specifically the `let res` stuff near the end. I feel like there should be a way to either get the second `Unix.tcsetattr` into a `finally` like block, or otherwise "wrap" the call to `f ()`.

How could I make this code more idiomatic? I'm quite new to OCaml, so any suggestions for restructuring this code would be useful.

```
module TermIO = struct
  let in_raw_mode (f: unit -> _) =
    let termio  = Unix.tcgetattr Unix.stdin in
    let termio' = { termio with
                    Unix.c_echo   = false ;
                    Unix.c_icanon = false 
                  } in
    Unix.tcsetattr Unix.stdin Unix.TCSAFLUSH termio' ;
    let res = f () in
    Unix.tcsetattr Unix.stdin Unix.TCSAFLUSH termio  ;
    res
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Comment: @Phrancis'DROPTABLEUsers-- edited the title, although it's a little unwieldy now. Hope that's better :)

Comment: Here, how's this? :)

Answer (score 1):

The sad fact is that your code should be even uglier. If `f()` throws an exception, you won't restore the resources correctly.

Idiomatic OCaml recommends that a recurring pattern can be described with a function. So you would define a function that takes:

- a resource (`'a`)
- a function to execute with the resource (`'a -> 'b`)
- and a function to free the resource (`'a -> unit`)

The signature becomes:

```
val bracket : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> unit) -> 'b
```

The `bracket` function would do the ugly `let res = f()` thing, but also wrap it with a `try-catch`.

UPDATE: The next version of OCaml (v4.08.0) looks like it will have a `finally`-type function added to the standard library: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/1855